# Implement WF4 workflow Resume without Bookmarks

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation-4, conceptual

Is there any other way to make a workflow resume at some state (state machine) without using **bookMarks**?

Thanks,

Comment: As an aside, do you know of any way I can eat an apple without an apple? ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Bookmarks are *how* a Workflow resumes. You can [read more about bookmarks here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489442.aspx).